# React parent state not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props

The state showMenu keeps returning false, it's not getting updated.

After my console.log in the parent, state keeps returning false, while I am clearly updating it in the function toggleMenu().

Can someone please explain how to fix this problem?

(Also how am I able to pass this new state back to my childclass to change my css class there?)

Please don't redirect me to related questions in stackoverflow, I already checked a lot of them but not getting the concept quite right so an example would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
CHILD COMPONENT


class GeneralNav extends Component {
  state = {
    showMenu: false
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <EasyFlexRow style="row-space-between header-nav-justify-content nav-fixed">
        <div
          className="nav-burger-box menu-action"
          onClick={this.props.toggleMenu}
        >
          <div className="nav-burger-top" />
          <div className="nav-burger-bottom" />
        </div>
      </EasyFlexRow>
    );
  }
}



PARENT COMPONENT

class HomePage extends Component {
  state = {
    showMenu: false
  };

  toggleMenu = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.showMenu);
    this.state.showMenu = false
      ? this.setState({ showMenu: true })
      : this.setState({ showMenu: false });
  };


render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
            <GeneralNav toggleMenu={this.toggleMenu.bind(this)} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you don't need `state = {
    showMenu: false
  };` in the Child Component as the state is already declared in the parent component, Then you can replace `this.toggleMenu.bind(this)` by `this.toggleMenu` as you are using arrow function. Please change `this.state.showMenu = false
      ? this.setState({ showMenu: true })
      : this.setState({ showMenu: false });` by `
      : this.setState(state => { showMenu: !state?showMenu });`

Comment: @brunelli, redirecting to other related questions on stackoverflow is an effective way of consolidating answers into one central place which helps make the questions easily found on the site and search engines. If someone has a related post that answers your question, they should share it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.state.showMenu = false
  ? this.setState({ showMenu: true })
  : this.setState({ showMenu: false });
```

is not correct, you should use `===` instead of `=` for the comparison otherwise `this.state.showMenu = false` will always return false. So it should be `this.state.showMenu === false`.

It would be more elegant to use `setState` like this

```
toggleMenu = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.state.showMenu);
  this.setState(state => ({showMenu: !state.showMenu}));
};
```

Note that you could delete `state = {showMenu: false};` in `GeneralNav` as the state is already declared in the parent component.

You could also replace `toggleMenu={this.toggleMenu.bind(this)}` by `toggleMenu={this.toggleMenu}` because `toggleMenu` was declared using arrow function so `this` will refer to the class instance

Comment: maybe you should accept the answer if your problem is solved

Comment: Additionally, it's worth mentioning that it's a good practice to use [Yoda Conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions), which would have made this _immediately obvious_.  If the condition had been written `false = this.state.showMenu`, it would have thrown an error which would have highlighted the typo.